# Time Machine only has files from today

Tags: time-machine

I have been using Time Machine to back up my school folders, on a My Passport, for 2 years now, I have never needed to restore files until now.

I opened it today to only find files from today. It says I have some 240ish GB used already, but I cant view anything older than today. I know I should have some PSD and CSW files on it.

Comment: You are using the TimeMachine app to browse to your files or Finder?

Comment: What size is your internal HD & your backup HD?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Time Machine app to browse your Time Machine disk rather than looking through the disk with Finder.

1. Navigate to the folder where the files/folders are missing in Finder.
2. Open Time Machine.app.
3. Select the files/folders to restore and click Restore.